# using grep to filter a line stream and prefix it with the detected pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, stream-processing

got a tricky question regarding filtering multiple patters with grep while modifying the stream itself depending on the selected pattern

if i want to filter multiple patterns of lets say "ps -ef" output i can do this

```
ps -ef |grep -E "client|postgres:"

postgres 142705   3845  0 12:04 ?        00:00:00 postgres: suiteadmin suiteadmin 127.0.0.1(34380) idle
postgres 142979   3845  3 12:04 ?        00:00:00 postgres: cost securetrack [local] idle
postgres 142989   3845 12 12:04 ?        00:00:00 postgres: cost securetrack [local] SELECT
root     142991 140798  0 12:04 pts/0    00:00:00 my.client -fce
```

however, i can't tell later in the stream processing whether the "client" or the "postgres:" patterns were matched for the specific stream line (which is crucial for my usecase)

if i choose to use -o argument, grep gives me the actually matched pattern from the multiple patterns i requested, but it will not print the entire stream line 
 it found the pattern in (which i also need)

```
ps -ef |grep -Eo "client|postgres:"
postgres:
postgres:
postgres:
client
```

i want grep (or possibly another tool) to give me "matched pattern" + "line with matched pattern" so i could later process it as a stream knowing "why" it got selected in the first place.

not so sure i can do it with grep
is there another tool i can use for this? (awk, sed, etc...)

its important for me to do it very fast and efficient so i don't want to start messing up with loops and multiple calls to different linux executable tools

want to keep it processed as a stream with a single tool that does both filtering by multiple options and also tells me which one of the pattern it picked it by

Comment: please add expected output to clarify your requirements...

Answer (score 3):

You may use `awk` for this:

```
ps -ef | 
awk -v kw='client;postgres:' 'BEGIN{n=split(kw, a, /;/)} {
for (i=1; i<=n; i++) if ($0 ~ a[i]) print a[i] "#", $0}'
```

```
postgres:# postgres 142705   3845  0 12:04 ?        00:00:00 postgres: suiteadmin suiteadmin 127.0.0.1(34380) idle
postgres:# postgres 142979   3845  3 12:04 ?        00:00:00 postgres: cost securetrack [local] idle
postgres:# postgres 142989   3845 12 12:04 ?        00:00:00 postgres: cost securetrack [local] SELECT
client# root     142991 140798  0 12:04 pts/0    00:00:00 my.client -fce
```

- Using `-v kw='client;postgres:'` we pass a `;` delimited keywords to search in the `ps` output
- Using `split` function we split list into an array `a`
- In the main block we check if a line contains any of the keyword then we prefix line with that keyword

Comment: works well. exactly what i needed. had a feeling awk can do the trick. but i almost don't know the syntax at all beside the regular print this sum that average that mambo jumbo. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$ ps -ef | sed -nE 's/.*(client|postgres:).*/\1 &/p'
postgres: postgres 142705   3845  0 12:04 ?        00:00:00 postgres: suiteadmin suiteadmin 127.0.0.1(34380) idle
postgres: postgres 142979   3845  3 12:04 ?        00:00:00 postgres: cost securetrack [local] idle
postgres: postgres 142989   3845 12 12:04 ?        00:00:00 postgres: cost securetrack [local] SELECT
client root     142991 140798  0 12:04 pts/0    00:00:00 my.client -fce
```

This captures the matched string and adds it to start of matched line

Answer (score 1):

Another awk:

```
$ echo foo bar | 
awk -v s="bar|baz" '$0~s{match($0,s);print substr($0,RSTART, RLENGTH) ":", $0}'
bar: foo bar
```

Give the search pattern in `s` variable. It only supports first match in line but is easily expanded to show them all.